# Can JavaScript detect when key and mouse events occur inside of a Flash application?

Tags: javascript, flash, mouseevent, keyevent

I've some very old Flash applications, which we don't want to rebuild to add a new feature.  We simply need to detect when the user has become idle.  So, if the Flash application receives no key or mouse events after 3 minutes, we want to track that time till the user interacts with the application again.

We've considered wrapping the applications in newer Flash applications to include the key/mouse event tracking; however, early research shows that some of our apps are so old that they use event systems or AVM's (ActionScript Virtual Machines) that are incompatible.  Also, it seems that mouse events on the inner application don't bubble up to the outer application. (I think the direction of event processing is backwards in versions of Flash prior to 8)

Anyhow, the next idea on the table is to see if we can determine when the user stops interacting with the old Flash applications using JavaScript.  Can anyone confirm whether or not it is possible to detect, using JavaScript only, when a swf in an HTML document loses focus or key and mouse events stop and start occurring on the swf?

Comment: i dont think it's possible that way cause the flash will get all the focus (mouse trap). i dont know since when AS did implement JS-Callbacks, but I think this would be the best way to do it.

Comment: Thanks androiddavid.  I was really hoping someone out there would say different.  I've also used JS-Callbacks and ExternalInterface; however, that would require rebuilding these old apps, which is so risky or in some cases most likely impossible.

Comment: Hm I think the best way to find out is giving it a try. I mean it's not that hard to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Without rebuilding you can't get any events from old swf file. But you can wrap swf up and get mouse events using jQuery:

```
    $('#swfDiv').bind("mouseenter",function(){
        $('#swfDiv').show();
    }).bind("mouseleave",function(){
            $('#' + divCursor).hide();
    });
```